# Convert WP7 project to browser's silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any ideas\tools how to convert `silverlight wp7 project` to `silverlight3\4\5` for browsers?

Comment: How do you want Phone specific things such as dialing a number, thombstoning etc to be handled?

Comment: @Erno, I am not using any phone specific things in my app (directly)

Comment: Interested to hear how this turns out!

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace generally works well. Replace PhoneApplicationFrame with System.Windows.Controls.Frame, PhoneApplicationPage with System.Windows.Controls.Page. That should get you quite far towards the solution. Create an empty WP7 SL project and an empty desktop SL project and compare the csrpoj files for some more differences - you will probably want to either move the WP7 files from your application to a new empty SL project or replace bits of XML in the csproj file.